# Replace digits in String url

Tags: java, regex

I have a String of url which can be represented as

```
urlString = String1 + "/23px-" + String2.
```

The amount of pixels is different every time (can be 23px, 19px and so on). The length of `String1` and `String2` unknown and varies. `String1` can also contain two digits but never in combination with "px".

I tried to use the `replace` methods that all my `urlStings` have, let's say, 25px:

```
urlString.replace("\\d+px","25px")
urlString.replace("\\d{2}px","25px")
```

but it doesn't work. Where's the mistake?

Comment: You need `replaceAll` (`replace` **doesn't** take a *regular expression*).

Comment: Thank you so much. Sometimes the answer is so easy!

Answer (score 1):

You were extremely close , replaceAll takes a regex. replace takes in a CharSequence/String. This works :

```
    String urlString = "String1" + "/23px-" + "String2";

    System.out.println(urlString.replaceAll("\\d+px", "25px"));
    System.out.println(urlString.replaceAll("\\d{2}px", "25px"));
```

> replaceAll(String regex, String replacement) Replaces each substring
>   of this string that matches the given regular expression with the
>   given replacement.